# Can't get a working node-webkit+sqlite3 offline app

Tags: sqlite, node-webkit

I downloaded a demo zip from https://github.com/zycbob/node-webkit-sqlite3-windows-demo, unzipped it. I downloaded the Win32 binaries archive from https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit, unzipped it, copied all the files, and pasted them into "node-webkit-sqlite3-windows-demo-master" folder.

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "node-webkit-sqlite3-windows-demo",
  "main": "main.html",
  "window": {
    "icon": "",
    "toolbar": true,
    "width": 1024,
    "height": "100%",
    "position": "center",
    "fullscreen": false,
    "frame": true,
    "min_width": 900,
    "min_height": 600
  },
  "nodejs": true
}
```

main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script>
    var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    var db = new sqlite3.Database('db');
</script>
</head>
<body>
Test
</body>
</html>
```

But then when I run **nw.exe** and the window appears, console logs

```
Uncaught Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
path\to\node-webkit-sqlite3-windows-demo-master\node_modules\sqlite3\build\Release\node_sqlite3.node    module.js:359
--> Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
```

What exactly should I do to get a working offline node-webkit+sqlite demo?